# Correcting for index error with "pass" but still getting "list index out of range" error?

Tags: python, arrays, range

I'm fairly new to python and I'm working on a bit of a complicated (but fun!) project. I won't go into too many details, but I've noticed that previous questions similar to this tend to be for very specific situations, which makes them more difficult for me to get anything out of, but surely easier for people to try to answer.

I'm essentially working with a 36x36 matrix (simply called "array" in my code), where the bottom-left corner is entry 0, the entry above that is 1, and so on until we reach the 36th entry at the top-left corner and come back down to the 37th entry being to the right of entry 0, etc. For a given entry, I want to know the values of the entries to the right, left, up, and down of the argument. Of course, there are several edge cases that won't have 4 neighbors, so I've made an effort to take those into account, but I am getting seemingly inconsistent errors.

Here's the latest thing I've tried:

```
def neighbors(i):
    neighbors_array = []
    if array[i+1] in array:
        neighbors_array.append(array[i+1])
    if array[i-1] in array:
        neighbors_array.append(array[i-1])
    if array[i+36] in array:
        neighbors_array.append(array[i+36])
    if array[i-36] not in array:
        neighbors_array.append(array[i-36])
    return neighbors_array
```

For an argument in the middle of the array, say 800, I get 4 values that perfectly match what I would get if i individually printed `array[i+1]`, `array[i-1]`, etc. But for an argument I know is in the leftmost column of the matrix I get an output array with 4 entries even though I'm only expecting 3 since the argument doesn't have an [i-36] element associated to it. For an argument I know is in the rightmost column, I get `IndexError: list index out of range`

I'm confused as to why both edge cases don't have the same problem, and I want to fix both issues. As for entries in the top and bottom rows, I also get an unexpected 4-entry output, with the exceptions of the top-right and bottom-right corners, for which I get the index error.

I've tried converting the array to an actual matrix, but the neighbors function output is more complicated and I get similar problems anyways, so I think I'd rather stick with the array.

Comment: It might be easier to work with a list of lists of your elements. For 2x2 that would be `matrix = [[1,2], [3,4]]` and the neighbours of `matrix[i][j]` would be `matrix[i][j-1]`, `matrix[i][j+1]`, `matrix[i-1][j]` and `matrix[i+1][j]` (for all those that are not out of range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work as a bounds check:

```
if array[i-1] not in array:
    pass
```

because as soon as you say `array[i-1]` you're going to raise an exception, before your `if` predicate is even done evaluating.  You need to check that `i` is a valid index *before* you use it as an array index.

This would be the idiomatic way of doing this type of bounds check:

```
if i not in range(len(array)):
```

For your specific use case where you want to "wrap" values that are out of bounds, I'd suggest using the modulo (`%`) operator rather than using bounds checks to individually wrap in one direction or another.  Just let math do the work for you.  :)

```
for neighbor in [i-1, i+1]:
    neighbors_array.append(array[neighbor % len(array)])
```

since `36 % 36 == 0`, `-1 % 36 == 35`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem you see is in the code `array[something] in array` (originally `array[i+36] not in array` and so on).

If we try to evaluate this step by step we get the following:

1. first `array[something]` is evaluated. That might lead to an `IndexError`.  If it succeeds we have some `value`
2. now `value in array` is evaluated which in our case will be always `True` as we did previously get the `value` from the `array` itself.

Solution:

For lists you should check the length of the list to prevent `IndexError`:

```py
if len(array) > i+36:
    do_whatever_with(array[i+36])
```

Pythonic aproach:

In python it is considered good style to "ask for forgiveness instead of permission", so instead of the if-in-range-do pattern you could use a try-access-except-cleanup pattern:

```py
try:
    do_whatever_with(array[i+36])
except IndexError:
    pass # because you just skipped the case in your original code as well
```